# Magento 1 : How to Solve 404 Error while exporting csv file on custom module

Tags: error, csv, export

I have facing issue (404 error /page not found error) while exporting csv file in custom module from system configuration.
if anyone known then please tell me how to solve this 404 error.[image]

Comment: did you found solution for this ?

Comment: yes there was a problem of admin routes in config.xml file nothing else